# Como hacer una función que reciba el código de una tecla y lo guarde en un string? sfml

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

Estoy programando un juego en c++ mas usando la librería SFML y quiero que al momento que el jugador pierda quede guardado su nombre junto con el puntaje obtenido.

El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
        mWindow->close();
    }

    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space){
        bullets.push_back(bullet.create((aircraft.getPosition().x+15), (aircraft.getPosition().y+40), -90));
        soundPlayershoot.play();
    }

    if (aircraft.isDead(false)){

        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Y){
            std::cout<<"key pressed";
            mWindow->close();
            Game game2;
            game2.run();
        }else{
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::N){
                mWindow->close();
                mWindow->clear();
                mWindow->draw(aircraft.Render());
                mWindow->display();
            }
        }
        std::string name;
        name = textIn(event);
        while ((event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code != sf::Keyboard::Return)){
            name = textIn(event); //la idea es que mientras la tecla no sea enter se guarden en el string
        }
        std::cout<<name;
        Save(name);
    }
}
```

La función **textIn()** que toma el código de la tecla y devuelve la letra correspondiente

```
std::string Game::textIn(sf::Event & event){
std::string name="";
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Q) name += "Q";
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W) name += "W";
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::E) name += "E";
//esto sigue así para todas las demas letras solo no las agrego para no alargar el código innecesariamente

return name;
}
```

La función **Save(...)** que crea el archivo de texto donde se guardan los puntajes y llama a la función **saveScore** que guarda los datos

```
void Game::Save(std::string nombre){
std::ofstream archivo("Puntajes.txt");

if (archivo.is_open()){
    aircraft.saveScore(archivo, nombre);
}
archivo.close();
}
```

la funcion **saveScore**

```
void Aircraft::saveScore(std::ofstream &archivo, std::string nombre){
archivo << nombre+": "+scorestr;
}
```

El problema es que al momento de ingresar el texto el programa explota supongo que es por un error en el bucle while donde se evalúa que las teclas presionadas sean distintas a enter, ya que antes en lugar de usar while use un if pero solo guardaba en el archivo, la letra de la ultima tecla presionada antes de cerrar la ventana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema.

Estás enfocando el tema de manera incorrecta. Si capturas y gestionas los eventos de teclas, recibirás cada tecla por separado creando un terrible galimatías, por ejemplo, si el usuario teclea:

> <kbd>BloqMayús</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>BloqMayús</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Vas a recibir 6 eventos `sf::Event::KeyPressed`:

1. [`sf::Keyboard::P`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142aaeac1db209a64a0221277a835de986e6).
2. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).
3. [`sf::Keyboard::T`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a19f59109111fc5271d3581bcd0c43187).
4. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).
5. [`sf::Keyboard::T`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a19f59109111fc5271d3581bcd0c43187).
6. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).

Y ni siquiera sabrás que letras quería el usuario en mayúsculas.

Si el usuario teclea:

> Pulsar <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> Soltar <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Vas a recibir 7 eventos `sf::Event::KeyPressed`:

1. [`sf::Keyboard::LShift`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a270db49f76cb4dbe72da36153d3aa45c) o [`sf::Keyboard::RShift`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a5be69e3b2f25bd5f4eed75d063f42b90).
2. [`sf::Keyboard::P`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142aaeac1db209a64a0221277a835de986e6).
3. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).
4. [`sf::Keyboard::T`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a19f59109111fc5271d3581bcd0c43187).
5. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).
6. [`sf::Keyboard::T`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a19f59109111fc5271d3581bcd0c43187).
7. [`sf::Keyboard::A`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142a9d06fa7ac9af597034ea724fb08b991e).

Sin tampoco saber exactamente las mayúsculas que quería el usuario (porque no controlas cuando se sueltan los <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

#### Propuesta.

Captura [`sf::Event::TextEvent`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/structsf_1_1Event_1_1TextEvent.php#a00d96b1a5328a1d7cbc276e161befcb0):

```
std::string nombre;

while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::TextEvent) {
        switch (event.text.unicode) {
            case 13: // Ha pulsado enter
                // ... haz cosas ...
                break;

            default: // Ha pulsado algo que no es enter
                nombre.push_back(event.text.unicode);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

En los comentarios:

> Por cada tecla ¿debo agregar un `case` al `switch`?

No. Bastará que hagas un `case` para los casos especiales (como salto de línea o retroceso) y asumir que el resto es texto.

> ¿Por qué `case 13` tu lo comentas como "has pulsado enter"?, ¿**event.text.unicode** devuelve un numero por cada tecla?

Si y no. El evento de texto introducido de SFML ([`sf::Event::TextEvent`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/structsf_1_1Event_1_1TextEvent.php#a00d96b1a5328a1d7cbc276e161befcb0)) contiene un miembro público llamado [`unicode`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/structsf_1_1Event_1_1TextEvent.php#a00d96b1a5328a1d7cbc276e161befcb0) que se corresponde con el valor Unicode<sup>1</sup> en UTF-32<sup>2</sup> del carácter capturado.

Así pues el evento devuelve un número, pero no es por cada letra si no por cada elemento Unicode capturado. El valor Unicode de <kbd>⏎</kbd> es el `13` y seguramente lo quieras tener en cuenta para detener la captura de texto.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) es un estándar de codificación de caracteres diseñado para facilitar el tratamiento informático, transmisión y visualización de textos de múltiples lenguajes y disciplinas técnicas, especifica un nombre e identificador numérico único para cada carácter o símbolo, además de otras informaciones necesarias para su uso correcto: direccionalidad, mayúsculas y otros atributos. Unicode trata los caracteres alfabéticos, ideográficos y símbolos de forma equivalente, lo que significa que se pueden mezclar en un mismo texto sin la introducción de marcas o caracteres de control.

<sup>2</sup>[UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) es el formato de transformación Unicode de 32 bits. Es un protocolo para codificar puntos de control Unicode que usa exactamente 32 por cada punto de control Unicode. UTF-32 es una codificación de longitud fijada, en contraste de otros formatos de transformación Unicode que son de longitud variable. Cada valor de 32 bits en UTF-32 representa un punto de control Unicode y es exactamente equivalente al valor numérico de ese punto de control.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Solo dos dudas que me quedaron al leer tu propuesta: 1- por cada tecla debo agregar un case al switch? y 2- por que case 13 tu lo comentas como "has pulsado enter", **event.text.unicode** devuelve un numero por cada tecla?

Comment: obtengo un error en esta linea: **if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEvent)** el error en cuestión es "expected primary-expression before ')' token". Cual es el problema? pensé que podía ser algún paréntesis faltante pero lo revise varias veces y no es eso

Comment: Un posible problema es que no haya escrito bien la instrucción en mi ejemplo pues lo he escrito de memoria y en consecuencia no lo he compilado... por ello: podrían faltar o sobrar mayúsculas en algún identificador.